# Using propensity score methods with multilevel time series data

Tags: multilevel-analysis, causality, propensity-scores, timeseries-segmentation, synthetic-controls

I wanted to understand whether it would be feasible to use propensity score matching/weighting/stratification on my data. I'm investigating a region of the world where a number of countries joined an international organisation, and I'm using multilevel interrupted time series analysis to understand what effect a country's joining has on people. There are a number of (sometimes annoying) features of the data:

- The entire country joins this organisation, and so every respondent within a country is affected by it (treatment is at the grouping/clustering level)
- The outcome of interest is at the individual/unit level
- Each country joins this organisation at a different time
- At each time point when data is collected for a country, the individuals are different (i.e., the data is not longitudinal for individuals; each person only appears once in the dataset)
- Data is collected at different times for different countries (e.g., Country A has data from 1986, 1991, 1997, 2000, 2005, 2015; Country B has data from 2003, 2008, 2018; Country C has data from 1981, 1994, 2000, 2013; etc.)
- Within this region of the world, there is data on countries before and after they joined the organisation, and data on countries that never joined at all

In a perfect world, I would like to say that joining this organisation *caused* changes in the individual-level indicator, and I believe that propensity score methods would help get me there. But each time I find a propensity score method, it looks like one of the above features of my data makes the method either challenging, impossible, or inadvisable to use (e.g., some approaches seem to be used when the individuals within clusters appear at every time point, other approaches seem to be designed for when only some of the individuals within a cluster receive treatment, and still others are completely inapplicable to multilevel data). I've also looked briefly into synthetic control methods, which looks promising, but it appears to not be applied to multilevel data yet. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It appears to me that you need to develop a customized model for this problem. If you provide more details on your data (literally sharing a chunk of it here if possible e.g. head(df) ) I could give it a go and make a Bayesian model (I don't know how to build a custom model for this problem in a frequentist way).